# Push notification issues in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am playing with my application which has Interactive ,silent and normal push notification. And notice two things which is not happen in other application which has push notification functionality.

1) When i off the switch of the "Show on lock screen" from notification center and i lock the phone then push notification sound play twice

**How to generate this issue**

step 1 - Goto setting > notification

step 2 - Find your application > turn off switch which has "Show on lock screen" label

step 3 - Lock the screen

step 4 - send the push notification

> first time it plays when push received but i off the option of "Show on lock screen" so it not display after when i unlock the phone at that time notification popup again and sound plays again

2) If i off the notification from setting > navigation for my application then also i got the notification if application is in foreground.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult result))handler
{
    //NSLog(@"didReceiveRemoteNotification fetchCompletionHandler :: %@",userInfo);
    self.completionHandler = handler;
    self.completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
    [self getNotiResponse:application didReceiveRemoteNotification:userInfo];
}
```

This method used for silent notification but when ever any notification comes then notification handle here.

Comment: This case is with messages only not relevant to my scenario.

Comment: just wondering, this is your whole code in didReceiveRemote.. ? or did you customise the notification (Sound etc.)  ?

Comment: @XcodeNOOB this is my whole code in function i just handle the response